# Не могу получить данные с сайта https://krisha.kz/ при помощи fetch() javaScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch, cors

Добрый день в приложении написанном на REACT сделал код для получения данных с чужого сайта https://krisha.kz/, но получаю ошибки:

1. Access to fetch at 'https://krisha.kz/a/show/666816937' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
2. GET https://krisha.kz/a/show/666816937 net::ERR_FAILED
3. Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch
   Сам код запроса:

```
fetch('https://krisha.kz/a/show/666816937')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(myres => console.log(myres))
```

Искал по сети ответ не нашел, но нашел что многие сталкиваются с этой проблемой, есть ли решение?

Comment: что значит не нашли решения? либо чужой сайт выставляет вам нужные заголовки, разрешая забирать данные. либо вы проксируете запрос через свой бэкенд

Comment: Я новичок в разработке, пока только фронтенд изучаю, значит чужой сайт не выставляет нужные мне заголовки, не разрешая забирать данные, так я понимаю? Про проксирование запроса через бэкенд читал, но с бэком вообще еще не знаком.

Comment: Подробнее изучите политику CORS